# Stop angular from updating table

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am using angluar js.  On my page I have a table.  Each record in the table has a col that is a drop down list.  When this value gets changed and the user clicks save, the page checks to see if the value in the drop down has already been used.  If it has, an alert message is presented and if not, then some code is executed.  My problem is when the alert/error message is displayed.  When this is displayed, I don't want the table to update according to the new value but it still does.  How can I prevent this?  I am really new to using angular.

```
$scope.saveDeviceUpdate = function (updatedDevice, deviceId) {
    var numDevicesForBus = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.deviceList.length; i++)
    {
        if ($scope.data.deviceList[i].BusNumber == updatedDevice.busNumber)
        {
            numDevicesForBus++;
        }
    }
    if (numDevicesForBus == 0)
    {
        dataService.updateDevice(updatedDevice, deviceId);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("This bus already has a device!");
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: It would help if you showed what variables you bound to the table, or how you repopulate the data.